# woocommerce variation/add to cart not showing

Tags: woocommerce, product-variations

so, I have coded a wordpress theme and integrated woocommerce with it. It has used only simple products for some time, and I was using a simple product to test codes, as it works fine. But I recently added a variation product and then, the add to cart button also gone ( variation select dropdown is there, but values are not bonded to drop down. 
[image]

If anyone can give me a hint, showing what I have done wrong, that would be a big favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got the same issue and it solved when I manually entered a price for the variable products. Unfortunately I didn't find out yet why I have to enter it, even for the same value. But it fixed it.

Hope it helps !